# Every coalgebra is the quotient of a cosemisimple.

Tags: proof-verification, coalgebras

I am trying to show that every coalgebra is the quotient of a cosemisimple coalgebra (I'm actually not sure if it's true or not).

Here is my attempted solution:

Let $ C $ be a coalgebra. We know that $ C = \sum_i C_i $ is the sum of its finite dimensional subcoalgebras. Let $ n_i = [C_i : k] $, then for each $ i $ there is an onto coalgebra map $ f_i: C_{n_i}(k) \to C_i $, where $ C_{n_i}(k) $ denotes the comatrix coalgebra of degree $ n_i $. Hence there is an onto coalgebra map $ f: \bigoplus_i C_{n_i}(k) \to C $. Now each $ C_{n_i}(k) $ is simple, hence $ \bigoplus_i C_{n_i}(k) $ is cosemisimple, and we are done.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: What are the coalgebra maps $f_i:C_{n_i}(k)\to C_i$ you found?

Comment: Those are the maps described by Corollary 2.2.2 of Radford's Hopf algebras: pick a basis $ \{ c_j \} $ for $ C_i $, write $ \Delta(c_j) = \sum c_i \otimes c_{i,j} $ for each basis element $ c_j $, then $ f $ is defined by $  f(e_{i,j}) = c_{i,j} $.

Comment: Nice fact, I didn't know. Thanks. Now, I don't see any mistake so your proof convince me. In fact, any finite-dimensional algebra is a subalgebra of a semisimple algebra of the form $M_n(\Bbbk)$, whence also the claim seems reasonable to me..